# Why use <form> with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

If I am writing an application where I can dictate that the users must have a modern browser with javascript enabled, what is the benefit of using the html  tag.

For instance if I submit all of my "forms" by doing something like this, but I don't actually have any form tags in my html.  I just build a datalist to pass through the data parameter of the $.ajax call

```
$('#submit_form').click(function(){
   var datalist='foo='+$('#foo').val();
   $.ajax({
     // ajax json here
   });
}
```

Why would I use the form tag in my html code?  I am sure there is probably a good reason, but a friend asked me the other day and I couldn't give him a good reason why it was needed.

Comment: If you don't need a form, either as a fallback or to serialize the data or for validation or anything else a form can be useful for, there's no reason to use a form.

Comment: Forms are optional -- you don't have to use them unless you specifically want to refer to items within the form and handle a form like a form...

Comment: The only other reason I can think of is that I'm not sure if validators kick up a fuss if they find input tags that are not contained within a form tag. If that sort of thing is important to your app, that could be a concern.

Comment: Don't you need a `<form>` in order to post a file (`<input type="file" />`)?

Comment: @DavidHoerster :  I think you can post a file from an AJAX call without the `<form>` element. However, for fallback purposes you might want an actual form, though the OP has specified he's requiring his users to have a modern browser with JS enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your server side fallback will cause the form to continue to work if the JavaScript fails for some reason other than "the user has turned it off" (such as a network interruption)
2. Having the fields logically grouped in a form will make them more easily navigable in most screen reader software.

Comment: 1.  Can you tell me more about how network interruption may play a role?  2.  What is a screen reader software?

Comment: 1. For example, user is on a train and enters a tunnel while downloading the page. The Internet connection drops, the JavaScript file doesn't download. 2. Screen readers read out content and describe UI controls over headphones/speakers so people with vision related disabilities can still use computers.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand about screen readers and that is a great point.  Tell me more about the Network Interruption.  I mean if a connection is lost, you not going to get much done on a website that doesn't use javascript either.  In your experience would you recommend to always use forms even if I can save some time by not using them.

Comment: If the network is lost *momentarily* then it can trash an attempt to load a file, and if that file is JS or CSS then, if the site is well designed it will still be usable. Yes, use forms, skipping them isn't going to save you a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

that and also
you can use the html 5 attribute such as "required" (not submitting the form if this field empty)

```
<input type="text" required = required />
```

or `<input type="email"/>` (make sure its a valid email address).
without a form this attribute will not work.
with this code you save a bunch of code in JS.

hope i helped.